# Typescript: How to pass a generic dict type to class so it allows to set empty object as default value?

Tags: typescript

I want my Entity to store some components in a dictionary like an example below. But I want the shape of the `components` dictionary to be passed on `Entity` creation.

```
    entity: {
      id: 1,
      components: {
        position: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        mass : {
          value: 4
        },
        color: {
          value: 'green'
        }
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, Typescript does not allow me to set the initial value of `components` as an empty object `{}`. I get the error `Type {} is not assignable to 'ComponentDictType'.`

```js
class Entity<ComponentDictType> {
 public id: number
 public components: ComponentDictType = {}
}
```

How can I constrain ComponentDictType so it becomes assignabme to an empty object?

Comment: Maybe `components` should be of type `Partial<ComponentDictType>` instead of `ComponentDictType`?

Comment: @jcalz, yay! It worked! Post an answer and i will approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can assign an empty object to `components` is if the type of `components` is compatible with an empty object.  One way to do this is to have `ComponentDictType` remain the full non-optional type but use `Partial<ComponentDictType>` as the type of the `components` property:

```
class Entity<ComponentDictType> {
    public id: number = 0; // init here too
    public components: Partial<ComponentDictType> = {}; // no error
}
```

(Note that I initialize both properties.  It's recommended to use both [`--strictNullChecks`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#--strictnullchecks) and [`--strictPropertyInitialization`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) to catch `undefined` errors before runtime.)

Now you can use your class, but be warned that the compiler no longer thinks that each property of `components` necessarily exists... you'll have to check it:

```
interface Components {
  position: {
    x: number,
    y: number
  },
  mass: {
    value: number
  },
  color: {
    value: string
  }
}

const entity = new Entity<Components>();
entity.components.color // {value: string} | undefined
entity.components.color.value; // error, possibly undefined
if (entity.components.color) { // check it yourself
  entity.components.color.value; // okay now
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!